# How to run python script linking to .so file within Cygwin?

Tags: python, linux, shell, cygwin

I am new to Python. I want to execute a python script inside which a shared library (`*.so` file) is included. I try execution on CYGWIN 64 (a Unix-environment on windows). It does not work and found this error: "OSEError: Exec format error". I think that the problem is from the `*.so` file. How can I execute my python script which uses the shared library (`*.so` file) within CYGWIN?

Comment: Was the library file compiled on Cygwin? If not, I don't think it will be able to be loaded. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: The library was not compiled on Cygwin. However, the script can be executed on linux terminal when calling *.sh.

Comment: Right, well, scripts aren't compiled. Compiled things are often specific to the type of system they were compiled for.